AlertManager fail starting up on kube-prometheus-9.0.3
kubectl logs alertmanager-kube-prometheus-alertmanager-x -n monitoring
Error from server (BadRequest): container "alertmanager" in pod "alertmanager-kube-prometheus-alertmanager-x" is waiting to start: PodInitializing

What happened: I've deployed the kube-prometheus as following command, and failed on 1 pods of  alertmanager-kube-prometheus-alertmanager-0. It keeps terminating.
What you expected to happen:
all pods/workloads should be running as expected.

Consider to ask sys-admin questions on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

I searched for the Prometheus operator in other namespaces, such as the default namespace, and then deleted the pod. After doing so, the alertmanager-kube-prometheus-alertmanager-x pod is now running smoothly.
